# RegEx pattern finds in sublime text but not in linux sed command sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have regex pattern to find and replace commas between quotes. It perfectly works in sublime text but not in sed linux command. Not sure what is missing here.

Reg Ex Pattern: `,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`

Sed Command
`sed -e 's/,\(?!\(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"\)*[^"]*$\)/\1\2/g' test.csv`

Comment: Different tools implement different subsets of all the possible regex features. `sed` supports a fairly limited set of features.

Comment: `sed` only supports "[basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03)", zero-width assertions such as `(?!)` are not supported.

Comment: Is there anyway to use complex regex pattern to find and replace the file content

Comment: @SelvakumarPonnusamy: You can use `perl` command line instead of `sed` or may be `awk` can also work. You should update question with a sample input and expected output.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: sed -r to use extended regular expressions ?

Comment: @ephemient GNU and OSX sed also support Extended Regexps with the `-E` option. @Roman `-r` does the same but only for GNU sed, not OSX.

Comment: @SelvakumarPonnusamy wrt `Is there anyway to use complex regex pattern` - why do you want to create a complex solution? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any sample input/output so it's a guess but is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ echo '"a,b","c,d"' | sed 's/"\([^"]*\),\([^"]*\)"/\1\2/g'
ab,cd
```

Given your comments below:

```
$ echo '"a,b","c,d"' | sed 's/\("[^"]*\),\([^"]*"\)/\1\2/g'
"ab","cd"
```

Comment: Im trying to replace only commas not quotes. I have achieved this using `perl -pi -e 's/,(?!(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/&#44;/g' <filename>`

Comment: Then just include the quotes in the capture groups. I updated my answer. You're really making this much more complicated than it has to be. What I posted will work on any UNIX box with any sed.